# Are Tenacious and Unsung Hero badges reclaimed or are the forever?

Tags: support, badges

I am about to get my long waited first Gold badge - Unsung Hero! But will I need to preserve the percentage in order to keep the badge? Or will the badge stay forever even if e.g. my answers get upvoted?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C3kna1iKAzw And for the satisfaction about real arts: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T8vqJJ68ykE

Comment: loool That's funny! :)

Comment: _"loool That's funny! :)"_ Sure they are funny! You'll never call out for _tenacious_ missing **D** anymore ;-) ...

Comment: "I am about to get my long waited first Gold badge" Not if I can help it! *<commences serial upvoting>*

Comment: :DD That's true, too bad for me. I'll have to answer more and hope that you forget to upvote some time in the future :)

Comment: @ZygD _"I'll have to answer more and hope that you forget to upvote some time in the future :)"_ Rely on **D** :-) ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Regular badges are forever, they are not reclaimed. Once awarded, it is yours to keep, regardless of what happens to your answer score later on.

That is, unless the moderators determined they were gained using heinous cheating, at which point they may ask a developer to revoke a badge. That's a highly irregular occurrence however.

*Tag* badges (expert badges), earned for a sufficient score and answer count against a specific tag, *are* revoked when you no longer meet the criteria, but are far more easily regained as well.

Comment: Okay. Nice to hear :) It seems that the Unsung Hero is a lot harder to obtain for those who specialise in more popular programming topics, like Android, Javascript, etc. I think those are the topics where they get more votes too :)

Comment: Yes, the badges are aimed at awarding those that work in the quiet corners of Stack Overflow, where the upvotes are not being showered about by loads of other visitors.